# déesse Famine de Baudelaire

Tags: sens, littérature, poésie

Parmi les poèmes de Charles Beaudelaire, il en est qui interpellent plus que d'autres comme [celui-ci](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Page:Baudelaire_-_%C5%92uvres_posthumes_1908.djvu/58), intitulé "oeuvres posthumes". Le quatrain suivant a attiré mon attention:

> Messieurs, ne crachez pas de jurons ni d’ordure
>
> Au visage fardé de cette pauvre impure
>
> Que **déesse Famine** a, par un soir d’hiver,
>
> Contrainte à relever ses jupons en plein air.

Ma question est la suivante:

Pourquoi est-il attribué à **Famine** le statut de **déesse/divinité**?

Une déesse est faite pour être adorée, mais ici je ne vois pas comment **Famine** peut-elle être adorée. Est-ce l'adoration qui est mise à mal ou alors la divinité?

Comment: Pour avoir le bon nombre de pieds dans le vers? ;-)

Comment: Pour la contraster ironiquement avec la déese romaine de l'abondance, l'inverse de la famine: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ops Aussi, il doit une avoir une déese grecque. Faut chercher plus.

Comment: Fames/λιμός, d'où vient le mot "famine".

Comment: C'est la faim qui pousse la prostitué à se prostituer et donc, voilà le pouvoir (de la faim) que le poéte érige en déesse.

Comment: @Lambie - please fix typos, as they are relevant on this forum.

Comment: correx: prostituée

Comment: @Frank French Language isn't a forum but a question & answer site. And typos can't be fixed on comments (just allowed five minutes). All one can do is delete a comment and sometimes it's better to keep a comment than delete it.

Comment: Well this is a problem, since it diminishes the quality of the French written on this public forum. It should serve as a reference for correct written French.

Answer (score 5):

Il s'agit pour moi de la création littéraire qui permet à l'auteur de créer des personnages et donc aussi des divinités.

En attribuant à la famine un statut divin, Baudelaire  lui confère une force et une autorité contre lesquelles la pauvresse dont il parle ne peut pas lutter et l'exonère ainsi de tout reproche de ses semblables de devoir se prostituer par nécessité.

C'est le même genre de création que quand on parle du Dieu Argent, de la Déesse Fortune, etc...

Comment: Mais la déesse n'est pas clémente ici.

Comment: @Frank On peut aussi voir les choses autrement effectivement...

Comment: @Laure Votre interprétation est séduisante. Mais je partage un peu le point de vue de Frank du fait qu'une déesse est faite pour être adorée. Il semble que cela ne soit pas le cas ici. Peut adorer famine?

Comment: @sapienz Les Dieux et les Déesses sont craints pour leur toute puissance avant tout, ils ne sont adorés (au sens religieux et pas par amour) par les hommes que pour attirer leur clémence. Mais nous sommes hors sujet. Voir plutôt sur [Literature StackExchange](http://literature.stackexchange.com/) ou 
[Mythology StackExchange](http://mythology.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: En effet, adorer pour avoir la clémence ou adorer par amour c'est pas le sujet ici, et c'est un autre débat.

Comment: La déese a le pouvoir sur la pute. Quant on a faim, on ferait n'importe quoi pour manger. Donc, la faim devient la déesse, celle qui a le pouvoir sur soi. Mais, normalment, les dieux et les déesses sont des êtres qui répresentent des choses, disons, positives, pas des choses négatives. Donc, le poéte utilise l'ironie. Personne adore la faim.

Comment: Je ne suis pas d'avis qu'un dieu est obligatoirement positif et adoré. Il peut être vénéré par crainte, mais pas forcément adoré dans le sens de chéri, pas dans toutes les cultures/religions en tout cas. Il ne faut pas oublier que les « autres » dieux en oppositions au Dieu chrétien (qu'on connait essentiellement) ne sont pas forcément miséricordieux. Je pense qu'outre la rime/nombre de pieds, il s'agit avant tout de mettre en avant, comme un fin Deus Ex Machina, quelque chose contre lequel on ne peut rien faire, contre lequel on ne peut s'opposer, et on se retrouver sans réel choix.

Comment: @Laure - Les dieux et déesses peuvent aussi être maudits. Mais je pense que votre interprétation, légèrement modifiée, est bonne: la prostituée n'est pas responsable de ses actions, car la déesse Famine la contrôle. Nous pouvons donc avoir de la sympathie pour cette prostituée qui n'est que le jouet d'une méchante déesse.

Comment: @Laure - ce n'est pas vraiment voir les choses "autrement". Ici, la déesse Famine n'est pas clémente, c'est un fait - mais cf ci-dessus, je souscris à votre interprétation (je viens juste de réaliser que vous avez édité le passage sur la clémence: nous disons maintenant exactement la même chose :-)

Answer (score 0):

Au delà de l'interprétation plus ou moins évidente que la Famine est déifiée pour exonérer la prostituée de la bassesse de ses actions (elle n'est que le jouet de la déesse), je pense que l'on pourrait aussi trouver une interprétation plus profonde dans cette déification de la Famine: la Famine contraint à la bassesse, que Baudelaire veut ériger en nouvelle beauté. Baudelaire trouverait une beauté d'inspiration divine dans la bassesse de la prostituée. Dans l'esthétique sombre et romantique de Baudelaire, il pourrait y avoir quelque chose de beau dans ce mal.

D'un point de vue encore plus sombre, dépressif, et dans la lignée des Fleurs du Mal, Baudelaire pourrait chercher à déifier tout ce qui rapproche de la mort en tant que délivrance du mal dans ce monde.

Je vois donc ici, en considérant la personnalité du poète et le reste de son oeuvre, trois interprétations qui se superposent et se complètent: 1. la prostituée n'est que le jouet d'une déesse, elle est donc *absoute* de sa bassesse ; 2. comme la bassesse de la prostituée est d'inspiration divine, elle est en fait *belle* ; 3. la Famine est déifiée car elle rapproche de la *mort*, *délivrance* ultime de la *souffrance* dans ce monde.

Je dirais que toute l'esthétique de Baudelaire est résumée dans cette déification d'un Mal: on en est le jouet, on en souffre, on n'en est pas responsable, c'est une croix qu'il faut porter, on veut s'en délivrer, mais la seule délivrance possible est dans la mort. Tout ce qu'il y a de plus Baudelairien.